# redux-form: Passing an _id to the submit handler along with formProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, onsubmit, react-props

I'm building an edit button for my CRUD app. In this component, each individual 'rating' is mapped into one of these components. The component starts out be displaying the rating as stored in the DB, but users can press the edit button, and it turns into a form! (eventually, I'll get initial values to populate the form fields with the data displayed in the alternate render option).

Right now for the edit button, I have a custom submit handler receiving the submitted data from the two form fields as 'formProps'. However, before passing these off to the backend API, I ALSO need to figure out how to tie an id or something to the submit handler.

As seen in the component right below the form, this whole child component has access to the necessary passed down from the parent which can accessed as 'this.props.id'. Is there anyway to bundle 'this.props.id' with formProps before the handleSubmit takes it all to Redux Actions?

```
class Rating extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        formClass: "notShowing",
        ratingClass: "showing"
    }
  }

renderForm = () => {
this.state.formClass === "notShowing"
? this.setState({formClass: "showing", ratingClass: "notShowing"})
: this.setState({formClass: "notShowing", ratingClass: "showing"})
}

onSubmit = (formProps) => {
    console.log("this is what the submitHandler recieves;", formProps);
    this.props.editRating(formProps, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/userDashboard');
    });
  }

render() {
    const { handleSubmit, reset } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="card darken-1" key={this.props._id}>
            <div className={this.state.formClass}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}> 
                    <p>What are you rating?</p>
                    <fieldset>
                    <Field
                        name="title"
                        type="text"
                        component="input"
                        autoComplete="none"
                    />
                    <p>Add your rates!</p>
                    <Field
                        name="value"
                        type="number"
                        component="input"
                        autoComplete="none"
                    />
                    </fieldset>
                    <button onClick={this.renderForm} type="submit" className="teal btn-flat right white-text">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <button onClick={this.renderForm}>Cancel</button>
            </div>    
            <div className={this.state.ratingClass}>
                <div className="card-content">
                <span className="card-title">{this.props.title}</span>
                <p>{this.props.value}</p>
                <button onClick={this.renderForm}>Edit</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteRating(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
                </div >    
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ratings}) {
  return { ratings };
} 

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, actions),
  reduxForm({ form: 'editRating' })
)(Rating);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of the `handleSubmit` function.

```
onSubmit = (values, _, props) => {
    console.log(values, props.id);
    ...
}
...
const { handleSubmit, reset } = this.props;
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} .../>
```

Reference: https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-onsubmit-function-code-optional-

Comment: Because without handleSubmit from redux-form being added as props, the submit never actually happens. There's alotta magic happening here in redux-form that I'm not educated on, so I couldn't tell yeah why that is.

Comment: You're right, that function needs to be called for the redux-form magic. I've edited my answer @ThirdGhostHand, can you try it out?

Comment: Hey!! Whatta yeah know.... I got everything I wanted! Cool. Thank you!

If you have the minute, do you think you could explain in layman terms where 'values', '_', and 'props' are coming from when we say we expect them in 'onSubmit'?

Thank you again!

Comment: Sure, please mark my answer as the Correct Answer if it helped you. It will help others find this question. So in the docs that I referenced, you can see that `handleSubmit` is automatically passed to your form component, and that function can accept your defined `onSubmit` function, calling it with three parameters: `values` (your form's values), `dispatch` (which i've just called `_` here because i'm assuming you're not using it), and `props` (which are your decorated form component's props). Take a look at the documentation I referenced in my answer.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I needed to know. Thanks again! You've helped heaps!